# Insert into table with value of auto increment column SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with primary key auto increment ID column.

In some cases, I would like to insert the value of the auto increment column into another column in the same table (Without update statement).

Is it possible?

Comment: A trigger can copy the value from one column to another, but that is still an update.

Comment: What do you mean by "In some cases..."?  Can you provide more detail as to how this decision is made and what type of target column you have?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in EF (without an additional update).  I would suggest creating an INSERT trigger at the database level. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this ID value go into another column of the same row when it does go in?  If so I would think that you could make this other column a calculated column that returns the ID column under certain conditions.

Other than that I can't think of any way you can put a value into place without an update or insert statement of some kind.  However when you end up doing it with an update or insert statement you can get the last ID generated using SCOPE_IDENTITY(), and you can also get the values that were inserted in some other statement by adding an OUTPUT clause.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx.